# How to display an element on hovering a different element

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked many times but I could not find the answer based on my requirement. The screenshot here is from flat icon. So when i hover an icon two icons appear which I can click. How to achieve that?[image: Screenshot of the example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do something like this

```
div.icon
  img
  div.buttons
    button
    button
```

When `div.icon` is hovered, the opacity of `div.buttons` change.

```css
.icon {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.icon>.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  
  /* Transition */
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.icon:hover>.buttons {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <!-- You can put the image in the background of the .icon div -->
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/0066ff/fff" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>Action 1</button>
    <button>Action 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a button or something which you want to display a value if hovered, you can simply use the following set of codes.

```css
#textToBeDisplayed{
  display: none;
 }
#Button:hover + #textToBeDisplayed{
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<button id="Button">Hover me!</button>
<p id="textToBeDisplayed">Button is hovered</p>
```

if it is a text box and you want a text displayed when it is focused just replace the :hover in css code by :focus